# what is an equivalent for 'fitna'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Fitna is a word in the Arabic language which, I believe has no equivalent in English only if 'Fitna' itself will enter English.

One meaning to it is temptation or appeal, but it's not that which I'm worried about it is the other meaning, maybe you can prove me wrong in averring to that there is no equivalent:

although some sources refer to it as sedition and civil strife, I don't think that is 100% accurate. Arabic Scholars (and there are not plenty considering that the bulk of Arab world speak dialectal Arabic according to their region/country) concur to that. As difficult as it is to explain, 'Fitna' is as I cited earlier is more than intricate to elucidate because a civil strife is not Fitna, it is part of the phenomena of Fitna. If one would elaborate the tale of Imam Ali and the reasons behind his death and that of his male offspring, maybe then and just then one would have a somewhat better understanding of the word. I understand the word but I cannot explain it patently and I struggle to explain it in my mother tongue due to its complexity.

To give you an element of hint: it is a jumble of fragmentation, chaos, unrest, scandal, disorder, mistrust, hatred, grudge and could include mass killings (between dissidents/family members/or other people (with no relation).. but dissidents and relatives is more common).

Reasons to Fitna: Religion, but not necessarily.
فتنة (in Arabic)

Thank you

Comment: This is a case where it would be highly unlikely for English (or any other non-Arabic) language to develop or adopt a single-word equivalent *precisely because of* all of the historical associations and implications that accompany the Arabic word. If English were to adopt and assimilate *Fitna* or if a new word were to be created to mean the same thing, it would quickly assume a uniquely English meaning based on usage and context that would still be missing most of the nuance you are looking for.

Comment: @bye "There is no such word" is a valid answer. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @bye English has adopted thousands of words from different languages, so why not follow suit in this case. The only word I can think of now is 'Intifada' an Arabic word present today in the English language meaning 'revolution/rebellion' introduced after repeated citation in Newspapers, the Media, Politics etc. 'Fitna' should be considered, Politicians and Historians do write it in italics and it's use is certainly on the rise.

Comment: DesertLion, there is no central governing body of the English language. And certainly the website EL&U has no power to establish *fitna* or any other word as English. Words become English by "popular demand"; if people find *fitna* useful enough in English-speaking contexts and start using it broadly and frequently, it will become "English"; if they don't, it won't. But asking *us* to "make it so" is a bit fruitless. Asking whether there's an *existing word* which has its meaning or fits its niche is on-topic, however.

Comment: DesertLion: to help explain what the cultural connotations of the word are, would you say that all the instances of 'Arab Spring' were cases of 'fitna'? If not, why not?

Comment: Like the [Reign of Terror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reign_of_Terror)?

Comment: @DanBron I certainly didn't ask for it to become forcibly English. All I said that it should be considered and ultimately it's only a personal opinion (a suggestion) although to my knowledge plenty of politicians around the world have used the word and they're not Arabs. It may and it may not be introduced but all I'm saying is if it does, it'll certainly nourish English further. @ Mitch The Arab spring would probably be regarded as Fitna although some would argue that it wasn't because of their political beliefs. I think it was Fitna and preplanned.

Comment: I think I would start with "feud": a state of prolonged mutual hostility, typically between two families or communities, characterized by violent assaults in revenge for previous injuries.

Comment: Also, *fitna* has an existing sound-alike in certain vernacular *fixing to*. "I'm fit'na call my girl."

Comment: Maybe something like anomie, anarchy, chaos, interregnum, civil unrest, disorder, disintegration, decadence, lawlessness, revolution, or similar terms, depending on what seems closest. There are no shortage of instances of that sort from world history: The Anarchy in 12th century England, the Warring States period in China, the Year of Revolutions of 1848 in Europe, the fall of the Roman Empire/Dark Ages in western Europe...

Comment: @DesertLion How could that ever work?

If one meaning is temptation or appeal and another is sedition and/or civil strife, there is no chance of any useful translation into English, or of English speakers adopting 'fitna' itself.

Can you Post some useful definitions and translations?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, it is a general concept and it is not only related to politics or religion (even though it usually shows itself in these domains.)

I think an equivalent (or near-equivalent) word is ***instigation*** or even ***mischief-making***. Also, it can show itself as a ***provocation***. But these words may not cover all the meanings of the word.

> When you instigate something, you start it, but the word carries conflict with it. If you are suspended for wearing a political t-shirt, the incident might instigate days of protest by students and faculty.
>
> Instigate comes from the Latin word instigare "to incite." People who are instigators often begin trouble but then back off and let others break the rules.
>
> http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/instigate

Though, as a terminology, it is used as *fitna* or *fitnah* in English and it gains different meanings in different domains. There are even differences between the meanings of the term in *Classical Arabic* and *Modern Arabic*. <sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitna_%28word%29)</sup>

Comment: Your suggestion *mischief-making* makes *fitna* sound almost childish, silly, cheeky and slightly irksome. *Instigation* is a much better candidate, violence is often connoted with it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Why would it be childish? It depends on the context. I tried to come up with generic terms that can be used in different contexts. It is not only used in violent situations.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mischief *wayward but not malicious behaviour, usually of children, that causes trouble, irritation, etc*

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That is one of the meanings of _mischief_. We are talking about _mischief-making_ and it depends on the context. I don't think _mischief-making_ connotes a childish behavior without a context. Does it?

Comment: I gave you my interpretation. I then supplied you with a dictionary definition. If you believe that riots and general turmoil can be described as *mischief-making*; the OP said and I quote: *although some sources refer to it as sedition and civil strife*. Then that's fine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I think _mischief-making_ can be used in political contexts too. You don't think so? You can prove me wrong but I'm not convinced. You know me, I edit my answer based on your suggestions too. For example you can check "mischief-making" along with "politics" or "riots" in Google Books and find examples in serious contexts. OP wanted a more generic term that can be applied to different contexts. "Sedition" and "civil strife" are used in specific contexts.

Comment: I have to agree with Mari-Lou here. Devoid of a specific context (and probably even overruling a specific context), _mischief-making_ sounds like harmless, somewhat joking, innocent prank-making. Though I have never heard the word before, the asker's description of what _fitna_ is sounds quite far from what I associate with mischief-making.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: [Google Books result](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=T0NdVN-QBoLM8geo64G4Bg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22mischief-making%22+riots&safe=off&tbm=bks). I also read more about "fitna" than what it is written in this question. As I said, it is not only used in political or religious contexts. OP meant that too. Also my answer covers more than "mischief-making".

Comment: Shall I call it "trouble-making" maybe?

Answer (score -1):

I don't speak Arabic, but one translation, possibly among the earliest, of the Classical Arabic interpretation of the word to English is;

> To burn

That's the translation given in Edward William Lane's [Arabic-English Lexicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic-English_Lexicon) from the mid-19th century, and it is my understanding that this is the meaning attributed to the word in the Quran.

*Burning* has a complex range of meanings in English, spanning from pain and suffering through persecution to desire and passion, so it's likely that *burn* and *fitna* overlap at least a little.